# python with object simulating multiple with objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

I want to get this behavior:

```
with Obj(param=1):
    with Obj(param=2):
        print(...)
```

using a single object:

```
with UnifyingObj():
    print(...)
```

I'm wondering how to safely implement the `UnifyingObj` class

This has to be a single class. I tried to do something like that:

```
class _DualWith:
    def __init__(self):
        self._with1 = Obj(param=1)
        self._with2 = Obj(param=2)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._with1.__enter__()
        self._with2.__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._with2.__exit__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._with1.__exit__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I don't think it's fully safe

Comment: You need to somehow elaborate your *multiple with objects* - the same objects, how many?

Comment: It's not a duplicate since I require it to be a single object

Comment: do you expect `param=...` to always be static `(1,2)`?

Comment: I can work with that if it's possible like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you NEED to wrap that behavior in a separate class? Maybe you could do something like this?

```
from contextlib import ExitStack


with ExitStack as stack:
    objects = [stack.enter_context(obj) for obj in [Obj(param=1), Obj(param=2)]]
```